# How to get the current logon user name in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web app, in the web.config, I have following settings:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain01\user01" password="***"/>
```

I deployed the app to Windows 2008 (IIS 7), the Identity of the application pool is domain01\user01, and in the Authentication of the app, I have following set:

```
Anonymous Authentication    Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation   Enabled
Basic Authentication    Disabled
Digest Authentication   Disabled
Forms Authentication    Disabled
Windows Authentication  Enabled
```

Now I need to get the user name who is currently logged on the machine, could be any authorized user with different domain. But no matter what I tired, I always got the impersonated user domain01\user01. I tried, HttpContext, WindowsIdentity, etc. Does anybody know how do I get the correct user name without changing my settings?

Comment: You can try [Page.User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) or [Environment.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx)

Comment: I tried. It returned domain01\user01, not the actual user who is currently logged on the machine.

Comment: Do you have IIS configured to use forms auth or some other authentication besides windows auth? It's possible you're authenticating with something else, and its pulling that instead of the windows auth stuff when you try to pull the user data.

Comment: Where should I check except the Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying domain01\username as the identity that you want to impersonate. That is why the current user is always that. If you remove the configured identity you will get the actual logged in user.

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

This is documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried to replace <identity impersonate="true" userName="domain01\user01" password="***"/> with <identity impersonate="true">, still not working.